# Writing to filesystem not console

Tags: c#-5.0

I want to write the numbers of all the bank numbers to an actual file. Not console version. But I dont see the actual files in the file system. How to write the numbers to the file system?

I have this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            string path = @"G:\Folder";

            //string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}-", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
            var bans = BankAcoutNumbers.BANS;          
            const int MAX_FILES = 10;
            const int BANS_PER_FILE = 10;
            int bansCounter = 0;
            var part = new List<int>();
            //string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);

            var maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();



                var fileCounter = 0;

                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                   DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                //var destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(fileName, fileCounter + 1));
                try
                {

                    // foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
                    //{


                    while (fileCounter <= maxNumberOfFiles)
                    {
                        timer.Start();
                        foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS)
                        {
                            part.Add(bank);
                           if(++bansCounter >= BANS_PER_FILE)
                            {
                                string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
                                //var destinationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                                //destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                                Console.WriteLine("NR{0}", fileName);
                                foreach (var partBan in  part )                                
                                    Console.WriteLine(partBan);
                                part.Clear();
                                bansCounter = 0;

                                if (++fileCounter >= MAX_FILES)
                               break;



                                //lineCounter = 0;
                                //destiNationFile.Flush();                                
                                //destiNationFile.Dispose();
                                //destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(fileName, fileCounter + 1));
                                //fileCounter++;
                            }

                            //destiNationFile.WriteLine(bank);
                            //lineCounter++;                   
                        }
                        //fileCounter++;                        
                        //}
                    }                       
                    timer.Stop();

                    Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.Seconds);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }



            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.

            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Thank you

```
public class Program
    {
        //BankAcoutNumbers bankAccountNumbers = new BankAcoutNumbers();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            string path = @"G:\Folder";

            //string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}-", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
            var bans = BankAcoutNumbers.BANS;          
            const int MAX_FILES = 10;
            const int BANS_PER_FILE = 10;
            int bansCounter = 0;
            var part = new List<int>();
            //part.Add(456456465);
            //string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);

            var maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();



                var fileCounter = 0;

                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                   DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                //var destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(fileName, fileCounter + 1));
                try
                {

                    // foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
                    //{


                    while (fileCounter <= maxNumberOfFiles)
                    {
                        timer.Start();
                        foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS)
                        {
                            part.Add(bank);
                           if(++bansCounter >= BANS_PER_FILE)
                            {
                                string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
                                //var destinationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                                //destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                                Console.WriteLine("NR{0}", fileName);
                                fileName = @"G:\\Folder" + fileName;

                                foreach (var partBan in part)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(partBan);
                                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, partBan.ToString());
                                }
                                part.Clear();
                                bansCounter = 0;

                                if (++fileCounter >= MAX_FILES)
                               break;



                                //lineCounter = 0;
                                //destiNationFile.Flush();                                
                                //destiNationFile.Dispose();
                                //destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(fileName, fileCounter + 1));
                                //fileCounter++;
                            }

                            //destiNationFile.WriteLine(bank);
                            //lineCounter++;                   
                        }
                        //fileCounter++;                        
                        //}
                    }                       
                    timer.Stop();

                    Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.Seconds);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }



            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.

            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code: 
Also please **take note** that for demonstration purposes I made **class  BankAcoutNumbers** which has  **member BANS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class BankAcoutNumbers
    {
        public List<int> BANS { get; set; }

        public BankAcoutNumbers()
        {
            BANS = new List<int>();
            BANS.Add(1456456465);
            BANS.Add(2456465);
            BANS.Add(342346465);
            BANS.Add(445645646);
            BANS.Add(545636546);
            BANS.Add(64556465);
            BANS.Add(7456465);
            BANS.Add(842346465);
            BANS.Add(9456456);
            BANS.Add(10456365);
            BANS.Add(11456456);
            BANS.Add(12456465);
            BANS.Add(1342346);
            BANS.Add(1445645);
            BANS.Add(1545636);
            BANS.Add(1645645);
            BANS.Add(1745646);
            BANS.Add(1842345);
            BANS.Add(194564);
            BANS.Add(2045635);
            BANS.Add(214564);
            BANS.Add(224564);
            BANS.Add(234234);
            BANS.Add(244564);
            BANS.Add(254563);
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string path = @"C:\";

            //string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}-", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
            //var bans = BankAcoutNumbers.BANS;
            const int MAX_FILES = 10;
            const int BANS_PER_FILE = 10;
            int bansCounter = 0;
            var part = new List<int>();
            //string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);

            var maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();



            var fileCounter = 0;

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            //var destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(fileName, fileCounter + 1));
            try
            {

                // foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
                //{


                while (fileCounter <= maxNumberOfFiles)
                {
                    timer.Start();
                    foreach (var bank in new BankAcoutNumbers().BANS)
                    {
                        part.Add(bank);
                        if (++bansCounter >= BANS_PER_FILE)
                        {
                            string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
                            string outputToFile = "";
                            //var destinationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                            //destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                            Console.WriteLine("NR{0}", fileName);
                            fileName = @"C:\" + fileName;
                            foreach (var partBan in part)
                            {
                                outputToFile += partBan + Environment.NewLine;
                                Console.WriteLine(partBan);
                            }
                            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, outputToFile);
                            part.Clear();
                            bansCounter = 0;

                            if (++fileCounter >= MAX_FILES)
                                break;


                        }


                    }

                }
                timer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.Seconds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }



            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.

            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. 
I tried this and got the following files at disc c: 42346465-456456465, 456365465-456456465, 456456465-456365465, 456456465-456465, 456465-42346465. Also inside of the files was content which I send to them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class BankAcoutNumbers
    {
        public List<int> BANS { get; set; }

        public BankAcoutNumbers()
        {
            BANS = new List<int>();
            BANS.Add(456456465);
            BANS.Add(456465);
            BANS.Add(42346465);
            BANS.Add(456456465);
            BANS.Add(456365465);
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string path = @"C:\";

            //string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}-", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
            //var bans = BankAcoutNumbers.BANS;
            const int MAX_FILES = 10;
            const int BANS_PER_FILE = 2;
            int bansCounter = 0;
            var part = new List<int>();
            //string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);

            var maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();



            var fileCounter = 0;

            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            //var destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(fileName, fileCounter + 1));
            try
            {

                // foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
                //{


                while (fileCounter <= maxNumberOfFiles)
                {
                    timer.Start();
                    foreach (var bank in new BankAcoutNumbers().BANS)
                    {
                        part.Add(bank);
                        if (++bansCounter >= BANS_PER_FILE)
                        {
                            string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
                            //var destinationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                            //destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                            Console.WriteLine("NR{0}", fileName);
                            fileName = @"C:\" + fileName;
                            foreach (var partBan in part)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(partBan);
                                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, partBan.ToString());
                            }

                            part.Clear();
                            bansCounter = 0;

                            if (++fileCounter >= MAX_FILES)
                                break;



                            //lineCounter = 0;
                            //destiNationFile.Flush();                                
                            //destiNationFile.Dispose();
                            //destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(fileName, fileCounter + 1));
                            //fileCounter++;
                        }

                        //destiNationFile.WriteLine(bank);
                        //lineCounter++;                   
                    }
                    //fileCounter++;                        
                    //}
                }
                timer.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.Seconds);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }



            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.

            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oke, thank you. but now in each file is just. A single file. And there has to be 10 lines in each file. I updated my post

Comment: Clarify your problem little bit better please. You mentioned, that you need to write in file. Function System.IO.File.WriteAllText will write in file with name fileName all, what is partBan string. It's up to you how you'll make filename, and what you'll put into partBan.

Comment: it writes a single line in each file not ten lines. But in the console I see ten lines in each file.

Comment: So total 100 lines in each file 10 lines. But now there is only a single line in each file

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx has nice function:

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt", text);

Comment: Thank you for your response.I triied that. I tried with  //string fileName. YOu see it in the code. But that doesnt work

Comment: Hi Yura, can you look at threat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085999/writinging-directly-to-filesystem. Because directly writing to file system, is much faster, but I only one single line in the file. Thank you