# Writinging directly to filesystem

Tags: c#-5.0

I want to directly writing to file system and not every line to a string, because that is much more time consuming.

I try it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string path = @"C:\BankNumber";
            var bans = BankAcoutNumbers.BANS;
            const int MAX_FILES = 80;
            const int BANS_PER_FILE = 8181 / 80;
            int bansCounter = 0;
            var part = new List<int>();
            var maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            var fileCounter = 0;



            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            try
            {
                while (fileCounter <= maxNumberOfFiles)
                {
                    timer.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("Start writing the bank numbers to file system");
                   // Console.WriteLine(timer.Start());
                    foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS)
                    {
                        part.Add(bank);
                        if (++bansCounter >= BANS_PER_FILE)
                        {
                            string fileName = string.Format("{0}.txt-{1}.txt", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
                            string outputToFile = "";// Otherwise you dont see the lines in the file. Just single line!!


                            string subString = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "nr");//Needed to add, because otherwise the files will not stored in the correct folder!!
                            fileName =  subString + fileName;

                            foreach (var partBan in part)
                            {
                                using(StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(fileName))
                                {

                                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, outputToFile);
                                }

                                //Console.WriteLine(partBan);
                               // outputToFile += partBan + Environment.NewLine;//Writing the lines to the file

                            }
                            ;//Writes to file system.
                            part.Clear();
                            bansCounter = 0;
                            //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, part.ToString());

                            if (++fileCounter >= MAX_FILES)
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                timer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Total time of writing the bank numbers to file system " + timer.Elapsed.Seconds + " seconds");
                //Console.WriteLine(BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Count());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I try it like this:

> foreach (var partBan in part)
>                               {
>                                   using(StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(fileName))
>                                   {
>
> ```
>                                 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, outputToFile);
>                             }
>
>                             //Console.WriteLine(partBan);
>                            // outputToFile += partBan + Environment.NewLine;//Writing the lines to the file
>
>                         }
> ```

Thank you

I try it like this:

```
foreach (var partBan in part)
                            {
                                using(StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(fileName))
                                {

                                    //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(subString, fileName);
                                    st.WriteLine(outputToFile);
                                }

                                //Console.WriteLine(partBan);
                               // outputToFile += partBan + Environment.NewLine;//Writing the lines to the file

                            }
```

But I dont see the content of the files. The files are empty

I try it like this:

```
public class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string path = @"C:\BankNumber";
            var bans = BankAcoutNumbers.BANS;
            const int MAX_FILES = 80;
            const int BANS_PER_FILE = 81818182 / 80;
            int bansCounter = 0;
            var part = new List<int>();
            var maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            var fileCounter = 0;



            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            try
            {
                while (fileCounter <= maxNumberOfFiles)
                {
                    timer.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("Start writing the bank numbers to file system");
                   // Console.WriteLine(timer.Start());
                    foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS)
                    {
                        part.Add(bank);
                        if (++bansCounter >= BANS_PER_FILE)
                        {
                            string fileName = string.Format("{0}.txt-{1}.txt", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
                            //string outputToFile = "";// Otherwise you dont see the lines in the file. Just single line!!
                            StringBuilder OutputFile = new StringBuilder("");


                            string subString = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "nr");//Needed to add, because otherwise the files will not stored in the correct folder!!
                            fileName =  subString + fileName;

                            foreach (var partBan in part)
                            {
                                OutputFile.Append(string.Format("{0}{1}", partBan.ToString(), Environment.NewLine));


                                //using(StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(fileName))
                                //{

                                //    //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(subString, fileName);
                                //    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                //    strBuilder.Append(st.)
                                //    st.Write(partBan + Environment.NewLine);
                                //}

                                //Console.WriteLine(partBan);
                               // outputToFile += partBan + Environment.NewLine;//Writing the lines to the file

                            }
                            //;//Writes to file system.
                            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, OutputFile.ToString());
                            part.Clear();
                            bansCounter = 0;
                            //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, part.ToString());

                            if (++fileCounter >= MAX_FILES)
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                timer.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Total time of writing the bank numbers to file system " + timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds");
                //Console.WriteLine(BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Count());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            foreach (var item in part)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoLongTask);
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Main thread ends");


            System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void DoLongTask(object input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread is background : {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground);
            Console.WriteLine("Input parameter : {0}", input);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

WriteAllText is not slower then StreamWriter. 
From the .Net source code here it how WriteAllText works:

```
private static void InternalWriteAllText(string path,
    string contents, Encoding encoding)
{
    Contract.Requires(path != null);
    Contract.Requires(encoding != null);
    Contract.Requires(path.Length > 0);
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, false, encoding))
        sw.Write(contents);
}
```

Slowness is caused by string. If to substitute string with StringBuilder perfomance will improve. Check this code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class BankAcoutNumbers
        {
            public List<int> BANS { get; set; }

            public BankAcoutNumbers()
            {
                BANS = new List<int>();
                BANS.Add(1456456465);
                BANS.Add(2456465);
                BANS.Add(342346465);
                BANS.Add(445645646);
                BANS.Add(545636546);
                BANS.Add(64556465);
                BANS.Add(7456465);
                BANS.Add(842346465);
                BANS.Add(9456456);
                BANS.Add(10456365);
                BANS.Add(11456456);
                BANS.Add(12456465);
                BANS.Add(1342346);
                BANS.Add(1445645);
                BANS.Add(1545636);
                BANS.Add(1645645);
                BANS.Add(1745646);
                BANS.Add(1842345);
                BANS.Add(194564);
                BANS.Add(2045635);
                BANS.Add(214564);
                BANS.Add(224564);
                BANS.Add(234234);
                BANS.Add(244564);
                BANS.Add(254563);
            }
        }


        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                string path = @"C:\";

                //string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}-", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
                //var bans = BankAcoutNumbers.BANS;
                const int MAX_FILES = 10;
                const int BANS_PER_FILE = 10;
                int bansCounter = 0;
                var part = new List<int>();
                //string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);

                var maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
                Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();



                var fileCounter = 0;

                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                //var destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(fileName, fileCounter + 1));
                try
                {

                    // foreach (var bank in BankAcoutNumbers.BANS.Take(100))
                    //{


                    while (fileCounter <= maxNumberOfFiles)
                    {
                        timer.Start();
                        foreach (var bank in new BankAcoutNumbers().BANS)
                        {
                            part.Add(bank);
                            if (++bansCounter >= BANS_PER_FILE)
                            {
                                string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", part[0], part[part.Count - 1]);
                                StringBuilder  outputToFile = new StringBuilder("");
                                //var destinationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                                //destiNationFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);
                                Console.WriteLine("NR{0}", fileName);
                                fileName = @"C:\" + fileName;
                                foreach (var partBan in part)
                                {
                                    outputToFile.Append(string.Format("{0}{1}", partBan , Environment.NewLine));
                                    Console.WriteLine(partBan);
                                }
                                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, outputToFile.ToString());
                                part.Clear();
                                bansCounter = 0;

                                if (++fileCounter >= MAX_FILES)
                                    break;


                            }


                        }

                    }
                    timer.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.Seconds);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }



                // Keep the console window open in debug mode.

                System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
                System.Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here is interesting article about string vs StringBuilder http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306822

Comment: Thank you Yura. One last thing. How can you fasten the process with:ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()

Comment: Avoid dead blocking, code which is executed by QueueUserWorkItem should be maximally autonomous and big enough in order to avoid switching of context, which also takes significant amount of time

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/729575/Thread-Pooling-in-Csharp-ThreadPool-QueueUserWorkI or http://tech.pro/tutorial/724/csharp-tutorial-using-the-threadpool

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I want to have it for every file, so there are 80 files. and in each file there are 1 000 000 files. Thank you

Comment: How it can be that in 1 file you have 1 000 000 files?

Comment: I mean ofcourse In one file 1 000 000 records(lines), ok

Comment: Iv done that: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090433/create-files-with-threading